# Creating a DATA Table for a JSON file on the front end of a svelte document

Tags: json, datatables, conditional-statements, svelte

I am very much a beginner in front-end development and I have written a script that takes the data from the front end and will be edited at the backend and returns the below JSON file in the example. I am trying to create a data table to show the returned JSON file of my edited JSON file in the back end. I get a JSON response from the backend which is stored in the variable d and then I would like to display the data in a table on the front end.

Could anyone please help me it is a bit confusing for me.

For example:
the response to the front end is,

```
d = {
    0: {{ "big_tree": "neem", "type": "plant" }, {"small_tree": "lemon", "type": "small_tree"}, {"meedium_tree": "mango", "plant": "fruit" }},
    1: {{ "big_tree": "other", "type": "plant" }, {"small_tree": "other", "type": "small plant"}, {"meedium_tree": "other", "type": "fruit" }},
    1: {{ "big_tree": "other", "type": "plant" }, {"small_tree": "other", "type": "small plant"}, {"meedium_tree": "other", "type": "fruit" }}
}
```

the table should be like this:

| big_tree | small_tree | meedium_tree |
| --- | --- | --- |
| neem | lemon | mango |
| other | other | other |
| other | other | other |

Comment: Compare your JSON response data structure to the [official example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html) for objects nested inside an array. Each object in the array contains the data for one table row. DataTables needs that array, otherwise it cannot iterate over the response data to create the table's rows.

Comment: Instead of saying "I googled a lot but nothing worked", you should try to provide a [mre] in the question. You can also read [ask] for more general guidance.